# Image from API not displayed in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, api

Im facing a problem where I am trying to retrieve data from an API and display it back. the API response an URL of the images like this `https://dazelpro.com/files/images/hanzo.jpg`. How i can fix this problem. Below also I attach my react code

Get request

```
    const kambing = () => {
    axios
        .get(`https://api.dazelpro.com/mobile-legends/hero/${id}`)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(`view by id: `, response.data);
            setHeroes(response.data.hero);

        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
};
```

Image tag

```
<img src={hero.hero_avatar}  width="50%" height="100%" />
```

API response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use map function to iterate over hero because the response.data.hero is an array object not a single object.

Comment: already map the state, i try to display other data is working fine but not for the image